# Send command, isn't something wrong with AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

So I have this game, called AirMech. It doesn't recognize mouse buttons as controls (yet) so I tried to use AutoHotkey to circumvent it until it's implemented.

```
#IfWinActive, AirMech
  XButton1::Send c
```

Didn't work. So I tried `SendGame`, `SendPlay` and everything else, didn't work either. I googled it, and found out that some games don't recognize any Send commands at all.

Before giving up, I just tried a simple mapping:

```
#IfWinActive, AirMech
  XButton1::c
```

It actually worked.

Is it expected than no Send command works, but the latter does? What if I wanted to trigger other actions ('c' plus a MsgBox, for instance)?

Comment: Thank you for showing just another way to circumvent the send problem in games. This will not solve most problems, since they fire a series of instructions with pauses in between and you have to use send(play).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoHotkey has the ability to send keystrokes in a variety of different ways (SendRaw / SendInput / SendPlay / SendEvent).  I'm not quite sure what approach the simple **key**::**key** mapping uses, but it must be one of them.  My guess is that one of SendRaw, SendInput, SendPlay, or SendEvent will work the same as **key**::**key**.

Also #IfWinActive sometimes doesn't work exactly the way you expect, especially with fullscreen games.  So I usually test my AHK scripts without the #IfWinActive to make sure they're working correctly.  Once it's working, I introduce the conditional.

---

**UPDATE**

From http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm:

> When a script is launched, each remapping is translated into a pair of
>   hotkeys. For example, a script containing **a::b** actually contains the
>   following two hotkeys instead:

```
*a::
SetKeyDelay -1   ; If the destination key is a mouse button, SetMouseDelay is used instead.
Send {Blind}{b DownTemp}  ; DownTemp is like Down except that other Send commands in the script won't assume "b" should stay down during their Send.
return

*a up::
SetKeyDelay -1  ; See note below for why press-duration is not specified with either of these SetKeyDelays. If the destination key is a mouse button, SetMouseDelay is used instead.
Send {Blind}{b Up}
return
```

---

My notes:

I suspect the reason `a::b` is working but `a::Send b` is not is because of how a::b breaks button down and button up handlers into two separate mappings.  The game's gameloop probably polls the gameplay keys for "keydown" state, which would not be maintained consistently if AHK is synthesizing repeats.  Remapping a_down->b_down and a_up->b_up probably makes AHK emulate more accurately the act of holding the key down, which may matter for programs which test for key state in particular ways (GetAsyncKeyState?).

The asterisk in the mapping means "Fire the hotkey even if extra modifiers are being held down."

Comment: Following your advice, I just gave it another try with all five Send commands, and without any `#IfWinActive`, just to make sure. To no avail: none is the exact same as key::key, apparently. Maybe a key delay thing (edit: according to @RobertIlbrink above, it sends pauses in between so that must explain why)

Comment: See http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm -- I pasted an interesting quote from that page into my answer.  Basically a::b is translated into two separate verbose mappings.  The entire page would probably be an interesting read for you.